# Usage of comma with "thanks"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, word-usage, syntactic-analysis, commas

Which of the following sentences is correct, and why?

1. Thank you Bob for scheduling the call. I look forward to speaking with you tomorrow at 4pm.
2. Thank you, Bob for scheduling the call. I look forward to speaking with you tomorrow at 4pm.
3. Thank you, Bob, for scheduling the call. I look forward to speaking with you tomorrow at 4pm.

I believe #3 is correct since commas are used to separate parts of a sentence to make the meaning clear and easier to read. However, English is not my native language, so I want to validate my understanding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right that #3 is correct, but primarily for a reason other than the one you mention. When you address someone or something directly, as with "Bob", you use commas to separate the form of direct address from the rest of the sentence. Hence, *Thank you, Bob, for scheduling the call.*

[Grammar Monster](https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/commas_with_vocative_case.htm) offers a clear explanation of the rule.

Comment: Thank you, Isabel, for the quick response, precise explanation, and link to a great resource.

Answer (score -1):

3 is correct, since "Bob" is a parenthetical (in this sentence you = Bob, so Bob could be removed without affecting the structure). The commas set off the parenthetical.

Comment: Thanks, Josh, for the explanation!